# Concat operations and get a result on basic calculator

Tags: javascript

I am having problems on getting the logic of it, I am doing a basic calculator and I am using switch instead of if to do some practice but I am having two problems I can't get to solve.

First, when pressing the equal button I am not getting the result of the operation, I am getting the result of "previous" or not getting a result at all.

And second, I don't know how to implement a concat of operations, like 9 * 5 + 45 - 35 (using the operators concats and throws a result), any ideas?

```js
const displayPrevResult = document.querySelector('.prev-result');
const displayCurrentResult = document.querySelector('.current-result');
const equal = document.querySelector('.equal');
const decimal = document.querySelector('.decimal');
const clear = document.querySelector('.clear');

const numberBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const operatorBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
let current = '';
let previous = '';
let operator = '';
let result;

numberBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
       getNum(event.target.textContent);
    })
})

operatorBtn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        getOp(event.target.textContent);
    })
});

equal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    result = operate(operator, previous, current);
    current = parseFloat(current);
    previous = parseFloat(previous);
    
    displayCurrentResult.textContent = result;
});

function getOp(op) {
    operator = op;
    previous = current;
    displayPrevResult.textContent = previous + ' ' + operator;
    current = '';

    if (previous !== '') {
        result = operate(operator, previous, current);
        displayCurrentResult.textContent = result;
    }
}

function getNum(num) {
    current += num;
    displayCurrentResult.textContent = current;
}


// Operating function
function operate(op, a, b) {

switch(op) {
    case '+':
        return add(a, b);
    break;
    case '-':
        return subtract(a, b);
    break;
    case 'x':
        return multiply(a, b);
    break;
    case '÷':
        return divide(a, b);
    break;
    
}

}

// Basic operation functions
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}

function divide(a, b) {
    return a / b;
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.calcContainer {
    background: linear-gradient(276deg, #40a179, #77cea9);
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0.1em;
    width: 40px;
    background: #a2ffaf;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background: #72e782;
}

.clr {
    background: #87e4bd;
}

.clr:hover {
    background: #53ad88;
}

.clear {
    margin: 0em 0.1em 0.5em 0.5em;
    padding: 0;
}

.output-clear-container {
    display: flex;
}

.output {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 40px;
    background: #c2fcca;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.par {
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}

.prev-result {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    color:#40a179;
}

.current-result {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calcContainer">
        <div class="output-clear-container">
            <div class="output">
                <div class="prev-result"></div>
                <div class="current-result">0</div>
            </div>
            <button class="clear">AC</button>
        </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">7</button>
                <button class="number">8</button>
                <button class="number">9</button>
                <button class="operator clr">÷</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">4</button>
                <button class="number">5</button>
                <button class="number">6</button>
                <button class="operator clr">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="number">1</button>
                <button class="number">2</button>
                <button class="number">3</button>
                <button class="operator clr">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="par">
                <button class="decimal clr">.</button>
                <button class="number">0</button>
                <button class="equal clr">=</button>
                <button class="operator clr">+</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have edited all the code but sitll don't know how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: Your switch cases are all the same (+)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just edited it (on my code was already updated) but result is the same for me.

Comment: Every time an "operator" is clicked, the code needs to check whether `previous` and `current` are set, and then call `operate()` as if `=` had been clicked. The result of that should become `current`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, I mean, I know what you mean but I just can't put it on practice, my mind just gets blank, could you please put me an example? Thank you